# Split string into parts of equal length c++

Tags: c++, string, loops, substring

I want to iteratively break up a string of arbitrary length into substrings of **length = 80** until the size of the final substring is either less than 80 or 0.
Assume the string is not divisible by 80 so length of final substring is not necessarily 80.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

string sub;

for (int i = 0; i < ceil(str.length()/80); i++) {
            if(str.length()/80 >= 1){
                sub = str.substr(i*80, 80);
            }
            if(str.length()/80 == 0){
                 sub = str.substr(i*80, str.length()%80);
            }
            if(sub.length() <= 0){
                 return;
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: One thing that's wrong is that it doesn't compile -- so readers can't just copy-and-paste it into a temporary .cpp file and then run it to see what it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ceil(str.length()/80)` is wrong because it's an integer division. `ceil(str.length()/80.0)` would work better. It feels wrong to be using floating point arithmetic at all however.

```
if(str.length()/80 >= 1){
     sub = str.substr(i*80, 80);
}
if(str.length()/80 == 0){
     sub = str.substr(i*80, str.length()%80);
}
```

Seems OK, but it's unnecessarily complex because it is allowed that the second argument to substr exceeds the length of the string, the rest of the string is selected in that case. So this `sub = str.substr(i*80, 80);` is all you need to do.

Here's how I would code it

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i += 80)
{
     string sub = str.substr(i, 80);
     ...
}
```

Comment: String is not necessarily divisible by 80 so length of substring may not be 80.

Comment: `if(str.length()/80 == 0)` should be `if(str.length()%80)`

Comment: @DarnocEloc The length argument of `substr` is allowed to exceed the number of characters in the string from the given position to the end. If that's the case, the string returned will be the suffix starting at the given position.

Comment: @DarnocEloc As I said, the second argument to substr is allowed to exceed the length of the string. It simplifies the coding.

Comment: @selbie Yes I missed that.

Comment: Then update your answer with the fix, so I can upvote it.

Comment: @selbie The error you mentioned is in the OPs code that I quoted. Not in the code I'm recommending.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would code it:

```
void split(const std::string& str)
{
    const size_t linelength = 80;

    size_t count = str.length() / linelength;
    auto start = str.begin();
    std::string sub;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        size_t startoffset = i * linelength;
        size_t endoffset = startoffset + linelength;
        sub = std::string(start + startoffset, start + endoffset);
    }
    if (str.length() % linelength)
    {
        sub = std::string(start + count * linelength, str.end());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the alternate solution to your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;


int main() {
    string initial_str =  "";  //your main string
    int len = initial_str.size(); // size of the main string
    vector<string> sub_str; // vector of substrings

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 80){
        sub_str.push_back(initial_str.substr(i, 80));
        //cout<< initial_str.substr(i, 5) << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sub_str.size(); i++) 
        cout << sub_str[i] << "\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```